# When using storyboards with Swift, how do I also include code?

Tags: ios, swift

I often look up questions about Swift regarding formatting and Views, and answers I find will include lines of code. If I am using storyboards, where should I look to include code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through the tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html

Comment: It's also unclear what exactly you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You include code to it's corresponding class.

let's say you're using a UIViewController in storyboard:

make a class of type ViewController,

and put the class name for it [image]

now both the class and the storyboard viewcontroller work together. and you can just add code in that class...

Answer (score -1):

Adding onto slimboy's answer, if you are beginner, you might forget to connect the IBOutlets/IBActions. Here is how.

1. You switch to double pane view with the storyboard on the left and the view controller on the right.
2. Then ctrl click from the view element to the top of the view controller
3. Name you view whatever (myTitleLabel).

Now you can use code to refer to the myTitleLabel. IBAction works the same, but make sure to change the option to Action (default is outlet in Swift).